# Active Model Serializers: parallel collections for efficient queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

Let's say I have a few models: `User`, `Place`, and `Review`. A `Review` is basically the intersection between `User` and `Place`, and `belongs_to` each.

We are returning several different endpoints that are centered around collections of Places, with attached Reviews.

To stay consistent with other endpoints returning places with attached reviews, I'm attempting to create a feed of the latest reviews created, like so:

```
[
  place: 'Pizza Pie',
    review: 'latest review!',
  place: 'Snuffleupagus' Shack',
    review: 'second latest review',
  etc. etc.
]
```

Here's my controller action (`expose` is from [RocketPants](https://github.com/Sutto/rocket_pants); it automatically calls `serializable_hash`):

```rb
def feed
  review_ids = Review.order("updated_at DESC").pluck(:id)
  expose Place.joins(:reviews).where(reviews: { id: review_ids }).order("reviews.updated_at DESC"), each_serializer: PlaceFeedSerializer
end
```

It will return the array of places and serialize each of them through the following `PlaceFeedSerializer`:

```rb
class PlaceFeedSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :address # etc. etc.
  has_one :review, serializer: ReviewSerializer
  def review
    object.reviews.order("updated_at DESC").first
  end
end
```

To accomplish this, I am making two up-front ActiveRecord queries, and then a new query for each serialized review. It seems kind of hacky, and slow.

Is there a way, in the controller, to pass in two arrays that would be serialized in parallel? Or, can I create an `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer` that would take in the appropriate `places` and `reviews` arrays?

Or am I overloading `ActiveModel::Serializer`'s simplicity, when I would be better off with something like JBuilder?

Perhaps another option, if possible, would be to serialize each review, "wrapped" in its associated place?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to consider using `:include` rather than `:joins` to eager load your `Place` info with your `Review` info. Relevant railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a rather hacky way of doing this, but it seems to work.

Passing in an array of Reviews from the controller, using `each_serializer: PlaceFeedSerializer`, it'll look something like this:

```
class PlaceFeedSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  delegate :current_resource_owner, to: :scope

  def initialize(*args)
    super
    @place = object.place
  end

  # Re-created association (need to manually attach in 'attributes')
  def review
    ReviewSerializer.new(object, @options)
  end

  # NOTE: This retrieves ONLY the attributes from PlaceSerializer
  #       so we need to create the associations manually (not DRY!)
  def attributes
    hash = PlaceSerializer.new(@place, @options).attributes
    hash[:review] = review
    hash
  end
end
```

If anyone has other ideas, feel free to contribute! Thanks.